# SASS & Compass Watch Failed Import

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have been struggling with SASS and Compass on my Mac OSX for the last few days.

I have a setup like below **(this is as accurate as I can make it)**.

Ive only done 1 site but there are around 40 with identical structure below proxysite1.com

**/Library/WebServer/Documents**

```
/WebProxy-Network
  /Global_Assets
     /_alerts.scss
     /_badges.scss
     /_breadcrumbs.scss
     /_button-groups.scss
     /_buttons.scss
     /_carousel.scss
     /_close.scss
     /_code.scss
     /_dropdowns.scss
     /_forms.scss
     /_grid.scss
     /_labels.scss
     /_print.scss
     /_bootstrap.scss (all the files above import into this one and will use shared by all the sites)
  /Asia
  /USA
  /EU
  /UK
   /www.proxysite1.com
         /scss
            _variables.scss
            _overrides.scss
            styles.scss (this imports _sass-bootstrap.scss, _variables.scss & overrides.scss)
         /css
            styles.css (ok so this should be the FINAL output unique for each site)
         /js
         /images
         /index.inc.php
         /index.php
         /config.rb
```

Inside my config.rb I have these settings:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

load "../../Global_Assets/Bootstrap3"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Now inside my /scss folder file styles.scss

I have the following:

```
// Site Overrides
@import "overrides";

// Site Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap3 SASS Framework
@import "bootstrap";
```

Right so that took a while but I want to get some good advice on where i'm going wrong ;)

Now when I visit this path via terminal

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/WebProxy-Network/UK/www.proxysite1.com/
```

and run the command "compass watch" I get the following message:

```
Ants-MacBook-Pro:www.antproxy.com Ant$ compass watch
>>> Change detected at 10:17:28 to: styles.scss
error scss/styles.scss (Line 24: File to import not found or unreadable: sass-bootstrap. 
Load paths:
/Library/WebServer/Documents/WebProxy-Network/UK/www.antproxy.com/scss
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
Compass::SpriteImporter)
overwrite css/styles.css 
>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

So hopefully this is enough info to get some good insight in to where I'm going wrong, hopefully its been clear and I'm on the right path :)

BTW the idea was to have it so I can specify different variables for each site allowing me to change colors fonts etc but share layout styles and functionality styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I would have posted this as a comment however I do not have the priviledges.)

I suspect that you may have gotten some of your indentations wrong in your post as running "compass watch" in the "www.proxysite1.com" directory while the config.rb file is within "assets" wouldn't work as compass wouldn't be able to find the configuration and would assume that no compass project existed.

Regardless, how are you including Bootstrap 3?

If you are not already using it already, I would recommend trying Thomas McDonald's bootstrap-sass. Available here: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass

UPDATE:

Why are you including Bootstrap 3 like this?

```
// Bootstrap3 SASS Framework
@import "sass-bootstrap";
```

If you have included the correct require statement in your config.rb (inc. below) then you should be able to import it like this mate:

```
// Bootstrap3 SASS Framework
@import "bootstrap";
```

Inside of config.rb, you should have this at the top:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'bootstrap-sass'

load "../../Global_Assets"
```

Comment: Hey, yes sorry was wrong it's not in assets it's in the site root. My bad, and yes I am usinng bootstrap-sass by Tom. I just didn't list all the files in the structure. I don't want to repeat the bootstrap 3 package on every site Hense I've tried to make it shared by all the site and only give them a variable file each and overrides. Leaving the core framework shared.

Comment: Ah okay, so assuming you have the "bootstrap-sass" gem installed then you will need to rename your bootstrap.scss file as it will conflict with the bootstrap that you are importing.

Then, once it has been renamed, change your import statement to be:

@import "bootstrap";

Comment: Also, don't forget to add the require to your config.rb file: require 'bootstrap-sass'

Comment: Even though they are named differently? appreciate your continued help :)

Comment: Yep, the official documentation (https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass#sass) for bootstrap-sass dictates that you must @import "bootstrap"; so if you have a file called "bootstrap.scss' then it will import that instead which would, technically, result in an infinite loop as it will be importing itself over and over.

Comment: ok, ive updated my first/initial post with renamed files etc and what terminal is telling me still getting the same errors :(

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look at how you are importing Bootstrap 3 (it should be called "bootstrap" not "sass-bootstrap").

Comment: still same error message line 24 failed to import not found unreadable bootstrap. really confusing :S

Comment: Could you please post the exact error message into your post? Also, did you add the require to your config.rb? If you do change your config.rb file, you would need to cancel your "compass watch" and re-run.

Comment: Ants-MacBook-Pro:www.proxysite1.com Ant$ compass watch
    >>> Change detected at 11:12:24 to: styles.scss
    error scss/styles.scss (Line 24: File to import not found or         unreadable: bootstrap.
    Load paths:
    /Library/WebServer/Documents/WebProxy-    Network/UK/www.proxysite1.com/scss
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
    Compass::SpriteImporter) 
    identical css/styles.css  
    >>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.

Yep I update all.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the following in your config.rb file? require 'bootstrap-sass'. I updated my answer to show you how to add it, just in case.

Comment: Amazing David! thank you so much! i was so close just a few small things think it was the Require which I had completely overlooked! Thank you! :)